# How to get the proper location of a image from input and display it using javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, src

If we get the value of location from input it returns something like-"file:///C:/fakepath/image.jpg". But when I set this value to the src of a image it says file not found.

How can I get the correct path of the image and set it to the source of the image?

Html:

```
   <label for="inputId">file dialog</label>
<input type="file" id="inputId"/>

<button onclick="setImage()">Show Image</button>
<br>
<img id="image"src="" width="600px" height="400px">
```

JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");

function setImage() {
var fileName = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
img.src = fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file and set its `base64` data to the `src` of the image:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("image");

function setImage() {
         const files = document.getElementById("inputId").files;
         if (!files || files.length==0)
              return;
         const file = files[0];
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = () => {
               img.src = reader.result;      
         };
}
```

```html
<label for="inputId">file dialog</label>
<input type="file" id="inputId"/>

<button onclick="setImage()">Show Image</button>
<br>
<img id="image"src="" width="600px" height="400px">
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what does files[0] means here?

Comment: The file you entered. It returns a list, so you need to specify the index of the file you want. So in this case, it is a one-file input, so you use ``files[0]``